# C# Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

I wrote a C# WCF server and I am trying to get it up in IIS but everything I try to go to my endpoint I get this error:
[image]

I checked the Permissions on the site and I have Authenticated Users others:
[image]

so I am not sure what to do now...

Comment: please improve your question quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that the root of the problem is that you are trying to create an application on the server that points to files on your own computer using a Remote Desktop Connection drive share.  The `\\?\UNC\tsclient\C\...` path is a dead giveaway.

This is a definite no.  You cannot run a web service this way.  The `tsclient` path is specific to your individual connection and will not work from any other context.  Any other user account - including the service account that the IIS instance is running from - will not be able to access those files.

To resolve this issue you need to copy the files from your machine to a location on the server and recreate the IIS application entry, referencing the location on the server.  You might still need to monkey with the security on the server-local folder.